# how to make sure SCSI is properly freed

Tags: usb-device, scsi

I have external SSD that I want to safely remove (as part of automation):

```
lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                   7:0    0  89.3M  1 loop /snap/core/6673
loop1                   7:1    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6350
sda                     8:0    0  29.3G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0     1M  0 part
└─sda2                  8:2    0  29.3G  0 part /
sdb                     8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1                  8:17   0   512M  0 part
├─sdb2                  8:18   0   732M  0 part
└─sdb3                  8:19   0 110.6G  0 part
  ├─goldVM--vg-root   253:0    0 109.6G  0 lvm
  └─goldVM--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   980M  0 lvm
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Running:

```
udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdb
```

Results in:

```
Error powering off drive: Error opening /dev/sdb: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

After trying eject/udisksctl unmount that didn't do the trick I followed response from here:

```
echo 'offline' > /sys/block/sdb/device/state
echo '1' > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

Which did lead to remove of `sdb`, but when I connect the device (unplug and plug again) it shows up as `sdc`, leading me to believe there is some occupied resource.

How to make sure all resources are properly freed, and ensure external device will be always connected to same device port?

Comment: You can try to use [man 1 eject](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eject.1.html) instead. Hope it helps.

Comment: not working, for now I have work around for not using the same device, it seems a bit ambiguous the inner working of the SCSI resource management